# Batch loop through a delimited by hash string, which contain spaces and commas

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, command-line, scripting

I have a string made of many parts separated by `#` char.
Some of the parts may contain spaces and commas.
I tried FOR loop but this doesn't work.

```batch
@echo off

set string_to_separate=11AAA#222 BB,333 CC,444DDD#555ee,77ff f#88g gg

for /f "tokens=* delims=#" %%i in (%string_to_separate%) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

I need result:

```
11AAA
222 BB,333 CC,444DDD
555ee,77ff f
88g gg
```

I need to use batch (.bat) file, what are the options to loop like this?

P.S. `string_to_separate` could have more than 100 parts(separated by `#` char).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work as long as there are no `!` within the content. It works by substituting a new line for each `#`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "string_to_separate=11AAA#'222 BB',333 CC,444DDD#555ee,77ff f#88g gg"
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('!string_to_separate:#^=^

!') do echo %%A
```

The method can support `!` within the content with a bit more code:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "string_to_separate=11AAA!#'222 BB',333 CC,444DDD#555ee,77ff f#88g gg"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('!string_to_separate:#^=^

!') do (
  if "!!" equ "" endlocal
  echo %%A
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The method below fail if the string contain wild-card characters: `*` or `?`.

```
@echo off

set string_to_separate=11AAA#222 BB,333 CC,444DDD#555ee,77ff f#88g gg

for %%i in ("%string_to_separate:#=" "%") do (
   echo %%~i
)
```

The method below have not any restriction:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set string_to_separate=11AAA#222 BB,333 CC,444DDD#555ee,77ff f#88g gg

set "str="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set ^"str=!string_to_separate:#=^
% New line %
!^"
for /F "eol=# delims=" %%i in ("!str!") do (
   if defined str endlocal
   echo %%i
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version for you to try. The first for loop determines which string to extract in the myEcho function. The myEcho function will not echo once the number of parts of your string are exhausted. So 200 is just an arbitrary number to ensure all parts are reported.

```
@echo off
set string_to_separate=one#two#three#four#five#six#seven#eight#nine#ten#eleven#twelve#thirteen#fourteen#fifteen#sixteen#seventeen#eighteen#nineteen#twenty#twenty one#twenty two#twenty three#twenty four#twenty five#twenty six#twenty seven#twenty eight#twenty nine#thirty#thirty one#thirty two#thirty three#thirty four#thirty five#thirty six#thirty seven#thirty eight#thirty nine#forty#forty one#forty two#forty three#forty four#forty five#forty six#forty seven#forty eight#forty nine#fifty#fifty one#fifty two#fifty three#fifty four#fifty five#fifty six#fifty seven#fifty eight#fifty nine#sixty#sixty one#sixty two#sixty three#sixty four#sixty five#sixty six#sixty seven#sixty eight#sixty nine#seventy#seventy one#seventy two#seventy three#seventy four#seventy five#
:loop
if not defined string_to_separate goto :EOF
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=#" %%i IN ("%string_to_separate%") Do (
  echo.%%i
  set string_to_separate=%%j
)
goto loop
```

Note: string_to_separate is now being continuously shortened and the script ends when string_to_separate is empty. If you need the original string, just copy it to another variable first.

Comment: This one loop only through 31 elements..., I changed string_to_separate to 280 elements and it stopped on 31.

Comment: @BlueMark, seems I was foiled by the 31 tokens limit in for loop. A few small edits and that's overcome - see modified answer.